# can HTML button both store in firebase and redirect page?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So far plugged in name and nickname gets saved in firebase successfully.
However, pressing button leading to another page doesn't work.

What am I missing?

**HTML (main.html)  part**

```
<body>
<form action="" id="user-form">

            <div class="inputBox">
                <input type="text" id ="user-name" required/>
                <span></span>
                <label>your name</label>
            </div>


           <div class="inputBox">
                <input type="text" id ="user-nickname" required/>
                <span></span>
                <label>your nickname</label>
            </div>


</form>


<button id="button" onclick="window.location='./landingpage.html';">Go</button> 

</body>
```

**index.js**

```
import {saveUser} from './firebase.js'
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { })

const userForm = document.getElementById('user-form')

userForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

const name = userForm['user-name']
const person = userForm['user-nickname']

saveUser(name.value, nickname.value);  })
```

**firebase.js**

```
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.14.0/firebase-app.js";
import { getFirestore, collection, addDoc } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.14.0/firebase-firestore.js";

const firebaseConfig = {
  the data from firebase
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = getFirestore()

export const saveUser = (name, nickname) =>
    addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {name, nickname});
```

I've tried href and onclick, but the problem is that when redirect works, firebase storing doesn't work. When storing works, page redirect doesn't work.

For example, the code here -- 'redirect' works, but firebase storing doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect *after* the user is saved, that's easiest if you move the `window.location='./landingpage.html';` into the submit handler:

```
userForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    const name = userForm['user-name']
    const person = userForm['user-nickname']

    saveUser(name.value, nickname.value).then(() => {
        window.location='./landingpage.html';
    });
})
```

So now it executes the redirect after the user has been successfully saved.

Update your HTML to no longer have the redirect:

```
<button id="button">Go</button>
```